# Regex filtering arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a regex:

```
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('')
  const pattern = new RegExp('\\b' + filterkeyword.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, ""), 'i')
```

An item in the products array would look something like this:

```
{
 name: 'Men's Shirts',
 price: 123,
 sale: 30,
 ...
}
```

basically, whenever a user types on an input, this keyword is being sent. I am then using

```
products.filter(x=> pattern.test(x.name)).map(product=> {return <Product />})
```

The issue I'm having here is that if the name of the product is "Men's Shirts" or "Women's Shirts" or anything that contains a {'}, the filter won't work anymore.
Any idea how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You clean the search text, but not the item names. You could clean the item names as well, so they use the same "allowed characters", giving a better chance of finding matches:

```js
const clean = text => text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "");
const products = [{ name: "Men's Shirts" }];

const getProducts = filterkeyword => {
  const pattern = new RegExp('\\b' + clean(filterkeyword), 'i');
  return products.filter(x => pattern.test(clean(x.name)));
}

console.log(getProducts("men's")[0]?.name);
console.log(getProducts("mens")[0]?.name);
console.log(getProducts("men‍s")[0]?.name);
console.log(getProducts("shoes")[0]?.name);
console.log(getProducts("shirts")[0]?.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
filterkeyword.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")
```

will remove any characters not matching that character set, resulting in a regular expression that may be missing characters. `Men's` type into search will result in a `\bMens` regex, which is not what you need.

Match alphanumeric sequences in the input instead, and check that all of them are included in the item you're looking at.

```
const searchedWords = (filterkeyword.toLowerCase().match(/[a-z\d]/g) || []);
```

```
products.filter(
  prod => searchedWords.every(word => prod.name.toLowerCase().includes(word))
)
```

While you *could* use a regular expression to implement the same logic, it'd be a tiny bit convoluted to construct dynamically. Using `.every` is easier and more intuitive.